# eclipselink hangs fetching data from cache

Tags: java, caching, concurrency, hashmap, eclipselink

Eclipselink hangs sometimes when I try to fetch some data (cpu usage goes to 100%). Debugging the code I see that the java vm hangs doing an HashMap.get(Object) operation ([here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzVhEBYMzDntZnd2RG8zaWFYWUk/view?usp=sharing) is the link to the stackTrace), and I suppose this is the well known concurrency issue on HashMap (see this [java bug report](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6423457)). In particular I see that the cacheKeys value of org.eclipse.persistence.internal.identitymaps.UnitOfWorkIdentityMap is an instance of HashMap and not ConcurrentHashMap. Could this be the cause of hangs in my code? How can I solve this?

To better explain the question the hangs occours when the jackson library is serializing a detached JPA entity, in particular when serializing a LAZY loaded list of object mapped as @ManytoMany.

Comment: The bug you linked talks about concurrent Map access, while a UnitOfWork is meant to be used one per thread so I don't see how they are related.  What is making the HashMap.get(Object) calls in your case?

Comment: @Chris I added a link to the stacktrace so you can see better. I suppose this is a concurrency issue because this is the only problem I know that can cause HashMap to hang with high cpu load.

Comment: Are you reusing UnitOfWorks in multiple threads, or passing around objects read from a UOW to different threads?

Comment: @Chris I don't use UnitOfWorks explicitly, I fetch a list of object from db, some of this contains links to other objects (fetch type is LAZY) and when the Jackson library tries to serialize the list i think  that the indirect list is retrived from cache and here is the HashMap.get(Object)

Comment: How was this list of objects read in?  Are they shared in anyway or passed around?

Comment: @Alepac - your problem is not due to concurrency issue in HashMap. You are fetching a list of objects which contains link to other objects (with LAZY loading), Are you closing the hibernate session before serializing with Jackson or you configured hibernate session in OSIV (open session in view)? If not then please do it and it will solve your problem

Comment: @Pavan I'm closing the eclipselink entity manager before returning the list

Comment: Are you using @Jackson in your Dao beans and serializing the Dao beans? Its not good practice to do that. You always create client or DTO bean for serialization and copy data from Dao to DTO

Comment: @Pavan I'm serializing the JPA entity himself (I suppose the entity is what you refer as DAO bean) and, in this case the I transfer the Jackson representation of the whole entity

Comment: @Alepac - Yes, I am referring to that only. That's why you are getting this issue. Please create client bean and copy your JPA entity to client bean. It will solve your issue. And Its not good practice to send JPA entity to client.

Comment: @Pavan - I understend and I will try to do this in my application but, why is not a good practice to do that, I closed the entity manager before serialization so I think the object is now a POJO, isn't it?

Comment: If you read JPA Specification, JPA entity have 3 states - Transient, Detached and Persist. After closing entity manager session, they are in Detached state. And If you are serializing JPA entity that mean you are giving exposure of JPA entity to client. As you have used @Jackson in your JPA entity, while serializing it will try to load all data and its sub data, so you will get bunch of data from DB which I don't need to so to client.

Comment: What version of Java are you using line 320 of HashMap seems like a old version. Also what is the version of eclipselink ? It might also help if you can take a full thread dump. I see only one thread in there.

Comment: @bhantol - I'm using openjdk 6 with eclipselink 2.5.2. Other treads goes on and ar not intrested on the issue at the moment of the dump.

Comment: @Alepac- Have you able to resolve issue?

Comment: @Pavan- I cannot test the solution now but my temporary workaround is to set the collectione EAGER (there are a few object in that collection)

Comment: Have you overriden hashCode() / equals() within your entity classes?